# What is the default caching status?

Tags: symfony

I am going over the symfony2 blog tutorial 
http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/extending-the-model-blog-comments.html
I am trying to add the comments and seems that doesn't change I think 
it's a cache issue. 
How can I force the symfony not to cache.

Comment: `php app/console cache:clear`

Comment: try `sudo service httpd graceful`

Answer (score 0):

By default, in the dev environment — when using the `app_dev.php` front controller — Symfony doesn't cache *almost* anything. I say “almost” because in some cases you have to clear the cache for some changes to apply — like adding a new translation file.

In the dev environment, Symfony doesn't cache things like controllers, routes and models, so your problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: I think he doesn't clear the cache after adding fields to an entity. Common pitfall.